# How is ng.cmd generated?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I’m looking through my companies JFrog dependency registry where they keep their verified/approved-by-the-firewall npm packages.
While looking through the angular cli package, I noticed that there is no ng.cmd file but after running npm install on my project directory, ng.cmd appears in node_modules/.bin

How is this file generated (on windows)? Or where is that file if it’s not generated?

Additional info: in case it helps to clarify my question, I’m asking this because the company firewall is expecting a specific hash value for the ng.cmd file. So after running npm install, my ng.cmd file keeps getting blocked. So I need to locate the file on the company registry and download it individually instead off of the package.json

Comment: npm generates the file when you install a package that supports command line. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding in case anyone needs this in the future:

as the comment above mentioned, the ng.cmd is generated after installing the package. It can be located inside the .bin folder in node_modules and can be blocked by many company firewalls if the SHA/checksum does not match the checksum provided in the firewall.